# Help understanding the derivation of the direct method for sensitivity analysis of ODE's

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The following is from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999176900073).

$\dot{y_i}$ is a set of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) with $t$=time and constants $c$.

$$\dot{y_i} = f_i(y_1, ..., y_n, t, c) = f_i(y, t, c) \tag 1$$

The solution of $(1)$ is a function of the variables $t$ and $c$, that is $y(t,c)$. To get the parameter sensitivities for a system of ODE's we introduce $n$ new variables that measure the sensivity of parameter $c$ to variables $y_i$. We consider initial condition parameters a part of $c$.

$$Z_i = \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial c} \tag 2$$

These are found as the solution to $n$ new differential equations $\dot{Z_i}$

$$\dot{Z_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(Z_i) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial c} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \left(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t} \right) \tag 3$$

The last part holds true because of symmetry of second derivatives. The next part is a statement that another way to write $\dot{Z_i}$ is

$$\dot{Z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \left[f_i(y(c, t), c, t) \right] \tag 4$$

It may be just the notation I'm having difficulty with, but I do not fully understand this statement.

Firstly, I want to check that I understand why we can write $(4)$ in the first place. This is because $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t} = \dot{y_i} = \frac{d y_i}{dt} = f_i(y, t, c)$. If this is not correct, then I do not know why  we can write statement $(4)$.

The second issue is perhaps just misinterpreting the notation and regards the first argument to $f_i$ in $(4)$. Does $f_i(y(c,t),c,t) = f_i(y,c,t)$ or does the $y(c,t)$ have some other significance here?

The next line is a statement that $(3)$ and $(4)$ can also be written as $(5)$

$$\dot{Z_i} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial c} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_i} \frac{\partial y_i}{ \partial c} \tag 5$$

Again, maybe this is a notational misunderstanding but if $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} [f_i(y(c, t), c, t)] = \frac{\partial [f_i(y(c, t), c, t)]}{\partial c} = \frac{\partial f_i }{\partial c} $ then how can we add anything on to $\frac{\partial f_i }{\partial c}$ without invalidating the equality?

Apologies if these are all noob questions but since I'm self learning there is nobody to ask.